# Python plot ticklabel overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, overlapping

Hey I cannot figure out any solution to solve my problem. The first tick labels keep overlapping. I found some methods to pad the tick label, but they did not work for a 3D plot.
Is there any way to solve this?
[image]

Comment: You can try to enhancing the figure size by `fig = plt.figure(figsize = (xx,xx))`. Maybe this could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly position and give the tick labels. If you are short on size consider setting the ticks yourself (alignment, position, names, font size, etc.). The following example does this for the Y axis tick labels:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x,y,z = np.random.randint(0,100,30),np.random.randint(0,100,30),np.random.randint(0,100,30)
ax.scatter(x,y,z)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 100)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 100)
ax.set_yticks([30,60,90])
ax.set_yticklabels(['number 30','number 60','number 90'], va='center', ha='left',fontsize=24)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 100)

plt.show()
```

, this results in:

[image: Setting up tick labels in Axes3D]

Obviously you'll need to see what works for the figure size you want and the values you want to be shown in your plot.